# unable to resolve module './fonts/Entypo.ttf' from '/home/pfe/node_modules/@expo/vector-icons/Entypo.js'

Tags: react-native, version, expo

When i try to run my application using expo i have this error :
**unable to resolve module './fonts/Entypo.ttf' from /home/pfe/node_modules/@expo/vector-icons/Entypo.js'**

**npm** : 4.3.0
**react-native-cli**: 2.0.1
**react-native**: 0.42.0
**expo@** 15.1.3

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I had that issue. Check last comment in https://github.com/expo/vector-icons/issues/8. If that doesn't work, then read all of the comments.

I hope that helps