# React native error just after run basic oroject

Tags: reactjs, react-native

[image]

I made basic app with react native, just after project initial I'm running the project and this is result,
I'm using expo 30.0.1, react 16.3.1 and react native SDK 30.0.0. Also I'm working on Windows 10.

Comment: check whether your packager is running. this usually comes when your app is unable to connect to the packager

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/43967521/2520628

Answer (score 0):

There are few things you can do to troubleshoot this error.

As the previous comment suggested. The most obvious solution is that your packager isn’t running. Xcode will run the packager when you press start but with Android studio once the app is installed on the emulator you have to run it yourself with react-native start.

The other things can be a little more subtle and difficult to source. The below are a few catch all fixes that might help.

Delete your node-modules then npm install.
Delete your package.lock file and npm install.

Hope that helps.